# pageinit does not called, in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

i am using [Remote autocomplete](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/autocomplete/autocomplete-remote.html) example of jQuery Mobile, i have implemented code and it is below

script is below

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js"></script>

       <script>
        $( document ).on( "pageinit", "#myPage", function() {
                alert("MOBILE");
         });
       </script>
```

html code is below

```
     <div data-role="page">
          <ul id="autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search Text..." data-filter-theme="d">
      </ul>
```

here the problem is that alert is not coming, can anybody help me how to do this?

Comment: you're using outdated libraries, use recent ones. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/mNjPE/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first include jquery file then add your code like below

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/js/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.js">
      <script>
            $(document).bind('pageinit', "#myPage", function() {
                    alert("MOBILE");
             });
           </script>
```

Comment: Sorry Rituraj but i have already added just not include here because anybody can focus on my problem i have included following line <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js"></script>

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> put ata the place of <script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>;

Comment: but Rituraj it is working perfect on that http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/autocomplete/autocomplete-remote.html example

Comment: on your view latest js name replace with jQuery.js so  main point is you include js file properly in your code it cant find jquery file

Comment: where? should i have to replace?

Comment: <script src="http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/js/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
put these files

Comment: This is totally wrong, `.ready()` shouldn't be used in jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Important: Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()
The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event. This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: thanks for focus @Omar i updated my code and i thing Op has file src issue not related to document ready and last thanks for focus